# Spring: How to return custom 404 instead of Resource

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a rest endpoint to deliver a file from the file system to the user through a `FileSystemResource`. If the file wasn't found it should display my custom 404 error page. But how can I achieve this? If I simply return a ResponseEntity with the status 404 the default error page is shown and not mine. I have other MVC controllers where if I enter an invalid URL my custom error page is returned. I tried to return a `ModelAndView` object and other things, but none seem to work.
Here an example for the download endpoint (just the important parts):

```
@GetMapping("/download/{fileName}")
    public ResponseEntity<FileSystemResource> downloadFile(@PathVariable("fileName") String fileName) {
        FileSystemResource fileResource= new FileSystemResource(STORAGE_LOCATION + fileName);
        if (fileResource.exists()) {
            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentDisposition(ContentDisposition.parse("attachment; filename=" + fileName));
            headers.setContentLength(fileResource.contentLength());
            return new ResponseEntity<>(fileResource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            //what to return here
        }
    }
```

The MVC part is covered by a custom error controller, taken from some examples I found:

```
@Controller
public class CustomErrorController implements ErrorController {

    @RequestMapping("/error")
    public String handleError(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Object status = request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_STATUS_CODE);

        if (status != null) {
            Integer statusCode = Integer.valueOf(status.toString());

            if (statusCode == HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN.value()) {
                return "error/403";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
                return "error/404";
            } else if (statusCode == HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value()) {
                return "error/500";
            }
        }
        return "error/default";
    }

    @Override
    public String getErrorPath() {
        return "/error";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find this yesterday (searched and tried stuff the whole afternoon), but here is the quick and easy solution since spring 5, just:

```
throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
```